# Loading local image into base64 in Expo / React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I have an image at `./assets/sprites.png`

I'd like to read it into a base64 string like this:

```
function loadSheet() {
  const bitmap = require("fs").readFileSync("./assets/sprites.png");
  const base64 = new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
  return "data:image/png;base64," + base64;
}
```

The only issue is, `fs` isn't a module. How can I do this?